# If network card supports 802.11n, does it mean it supports 5ghz band?

Tags: networking, windows-7, wifi, 802.1

I've gotten a new router that broadcasts 2.4ghz and 5ghz bands. But my desktop could only see the 2.4ghz connection.

I read from a website that as long as my network adapter supports 802.11a or 802.11n network modes, this means that the computer that you are using has the 5 GHz network capability.

I ran the command `netsh wlan show drivers` in console, and I do see that it supports 802.11n.

[image]

Does this mean that my wireless network card should support 5ghz network band?

Comment: 802.11n is a protocol. It can be used on any frequency. Unless your card says it supports 802.11a also, it probably only has the hardware to support 2.4ghz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Dell 1703 uses the Atheros AR9485 chip (`PCI\VEN_168C&DEV_0032`)

```
%ATHR.DeviceDesc.3119%     = ATHR_DEV_OS61_3119.ndi,    PCI\VEN_168C&DEV_0032&SUBSYS_02091028
ATHR.DeviceDesc.3119         = "Dell Wireless 1703 802.11b/g/n (2.4GHz)"
```

, which [only supports 2.4GHz](http://www.qca.qualcomm.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/AR9485.pdf).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking when a wifi product today refers to both 2.4GHz and 5GHz compatibility, it's referring to wifi using the 802.11ac standard.

While some of the prior standards did technically support 5GHz, finding hardware that actually implemented this was difficult.

You'll want a new wifi card that implements 802.11ac if you want to take advantage.

Comment: Not exactly true since 802.11.n and 802.11a both have been using the 5ghz spectrum for years. Dual band 802.11n routers are very common.